# Angular 6 - Jasmine - mock httpClient get map and error flows

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, mocking, angular6, angular-httpclient

I'm new to Angular testing and am trying to figure out how to write a test that mocks an error response of HttpClient.get() function. Basically my service has both map() and catchError() inside of its pipe() and I would like to excercise both flows. Here's what I have so far:

my.service.ts:

```
getItems(): Observable<ItemViewModels[]> {
    return 
        this.httpClient.get<any>(this.getItemsUrl)
        .pipe(
            map(json => {
                return json.map(itemJson => this.getVmFromItemJson(itemJson));
            }),
            catchError(() => {
                // Log stuff here...
                return of(null);
            })
        );
}
```

my.service.spec.ts:

```
it('should catch error and return null if API returns error', () => {
    spyOn(service.httpClient, 'get').and.returnValue(new Observable()); // Mock error here
    service.getItems().subscribe($items => expect($items).toBe(null));
});

it('should return valid view model array if API returns a valid json', () => {
    const mockResponse = [
        new SideNavItemViewModel(1),
        new SideNavItemViewModel(2),
        new SideNavItemViewModel(3)
    ];

    spyOn(service.httpClient, 'get').and.returnValue(of(JSON.stringify(mockResponse)));
    service.getSidenavViewModel().subscribe(x => expect(x).toBe(mockResponse));
});
```

So the actual issue is that the observables that I mock for the httpClient to return on get in the unit tests don't seem to get into the .pipe() function, which means that my tests aren't working :(

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried injecting your service into the test? I also try test the function that subscribes to the api call instead of creating another subscribe:

for errors:

```
it('should display error when server error occurs',
    inject([HttpTestingController, AService],
        (httpMock: HttpTestingController, svc: MyService) => {

        svc.getItems(); // has the subscribe in it

        const callingURL = svc['API']; // your api call eg. data/items

        httpMock.expectOne((req: HttpRequest < any > ) => req.url.indexOf(callingURL) !== -1)
        .error(new ErrorEvent('Customer Error', {
                error: 500
            }), {
            status: 500,
            statusText: 'Internal Server Error'
        });

        httpMock.verify();

        expect(component.svc.Jobs).toBeUndefined();

        fixture.detectChanges();

        // UI check here

    }));
```

data test

```
it('should display the correct amount of data elements',
    inject([HttpTestingController, AService],
        (httpMock: HttpTestingController, svc: MyService) => {

        svc.getItems();  // has the subscribe in it

        const callingURL = svc['API']; // your api call eg. data/items

        const mockReq = httpMock.expectOne((req: HttpRequest < any > ) => req.url.indexOf(callingURL) !== -1);

        mockReq.flush(mockData);

        httpMock.verify();

        expect(component.svc.data.length).toBe(mockData.length);

        fixture.detectChanges();
        // UI check here

    }));
```

So basically these functions:

- call your get and subscribe
- checks that your api url is contained in the http call
- mocks the response - you pass in the data - 'mockData'
- mockReq.flush(mockData); will trigger the call
- httpMock.verify(); will check the url and other things
- now the service data can be tested - if you subscribe sets anything in there
- fixture.detectChanges(); - then this will allow to test ui components

I prefer this way because you can keep your logic and tests separate.